# Identifying Matrices of Permutations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $B=${$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$}. For $\pi\in S_n$ define the linear transformation $T_\pi:V \to V$ by $T(v_i)=v_{\pi(i)}$ for $1\le i \le n$. Let $M_\pi$ denote the matrix of $T_\pi$ with respect to the basis $B$ and let $\mathcal M_n$ denote the set of such matrices.

Let $M_\pi$$=(m_{ij})_{1\le i,j, \le n}$. Show that

$$m_{ij} =\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $i=\pi(j)$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

*When I write out the problem I get that

$$m_{ij} =\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $\pi(i)=j$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

For example if $v_{\pi(1)}=v_3$ the permutation matrix should have a 1 in row 1 column 3. Am I missing something or did my professor perhaps write the problem out incorerectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column of $M$ would be $T(v_1)=v_{\pi(1)}$, which has $1$ as its 3rd component. That is, $M_{31}=1$. So your professor is correct.

Comment: I don't understand why its the first column not row.         $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$  $\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\\\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\2\\4\\\end{pmatrix}$

So M here represents a permutation, and T(1)=3, and there is a one in row one column 3, i.e. $\pi(i)=j$

Comment: I am not really sure about your example here. This matrix maps $v_1$ to $v_2$, $v_3$ to $v_1$.

Comment: The permutation matrix Pπ corresponding to the permutation $\pi$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3 \end{pmatrix} is $ P_\pi = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{e}_{\pi(1)} \\ \mathbf{e}_{\pi(2)} \\ \mathbf{e}_{\pi(3)} \\ \mathbf{e}_{\pi(4)} \\ \mathbf{e}_{\pi(5)} \end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{e}_{1} \\ \mathbf{e}_{4} \\ \mathbf{e}_{2} \\ \mathbf{e}_{5} \\ \mathbf{e}_{3} \end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: I just copied this straight off wikipedia. Here we see $\pi(2)$=4, and sure enough there is a one in row 2 column 4. I.e. there is a one where $\pi(i)=j$

Comment: The T in your definition is not the P they have. Use the fact $T(v_i)=v_{\pi(i)}$ will give you the transpose of their P. Your $T$ is actually defined to be $[e_{\pi_{(1)}} e_{\pi_{(2)}}...]$ where $e$ are columns. This is usually how linear transformation is defined.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thank you!